# How can I Delete a users(not just disable)

Tags: settings, user

I would like to delete the account because I'm not using it anymore.

In user's account setting...

the only option I see is **Disable User Account**

[image]

How can I permanently **Delete** the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plus (+) and a minus (-) button at the bottom left corner of the User Accounts window to add or delete accounts.

To delete an account, select the account and click on the minus button. You need to be an Administrator to delete an account.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try old school, text terminal approach:

`deluser [options] <user>`

Try `man deluser` first to get more information.

Certainly one should remove users while having administrator privileges, so either `su -` or `sudo` would be handy, too.